Why Does well water chlorine pump sometimes inject high levels of chlorine into the water
I have a submersible well pump 180ft. Deep . Known to be 20 or more years old, possibly 40 years old. I have a pulsatron chemical feed pump with 15 gallon barrel of chlorine that is injected into the water line as soon as the pipes enter the house, then connected is pressure tank, then 120 gallon holding/contact tank.  Then 10" X 50" filter designed for my water, then the softener tank and brine barrel. Couple things happen for a long time. If I leave the house fir a week. The chlorinator has always losed prime, even though I replaced it's parts with Kop kit and that backwashing is happening every other day with the filter and softener tanks. Big problem is that every couple weeks it seems  that when we wash clothes or take showers the chlorine levels are elevated that it bleaches the clothes with noticeable bleach spots and the chlorine smell and gas is evident through the shower head faucets etc. During this time the chlorine level has dropped dramatically. Now the power from the panel goes to the Franklin control box, then power goes out to the well pump and power goes out to from the control box to the  pressure switch and from the pressure switch power goes to the outlet that the chlorinator pump is plugged into . So when the faucets, showers etc call for water and the pressure switch drops to 40 pound.  The well pump should turn on along with the chlorine pump. I suspect that the well pump is worn and doesn't always activate, but I'm not sure and no one has addressed this on the internet forums. What do you all suspect is the issue.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

A 20 year old pump might be nearing end of life, depends on the pump/water.  The pressure switch might be weak as well.  A new pressure switch is the easiest/cheapest to replace in the system.  It can also be the settings on the chemical pump are off.  It can be a loose/dirty connection somewhere.  Too many places where the problem could be and too many expensive things to try replace to find the the problem, instead of testing to find the problem.

I've been managing a system nearly identical to that which you describe. I installed it from a diagram (and parts) supplied by the local plumbing supply company.
Key aspects of this type of system involve a proper setting for the chlorine feeder pump. If the setting is too high, you'll get too much chlorine injected. Immediately after the settling tank should be the carbon filter, which is used to remove the chlorine from the system.
You should have a tap between the settling tank and the carbon filter, to provide an indication of the concentration of chlorine being passed by the settling tank. The objective is to have a minimal reading (not zero) at that point.
If your filter tank has become overused, it will do little to keep the chlorine level at check. If the chlorine concentration is too high, the filter tank will fail too soon.
If you don't know when the filter media has been changed, it's probably your first task. Once the media is changed, you should buy chlorine test strips from the local pool supplies store, which may be where you get your chlorine. Your objective is nearly zero chlorine indication at the output of the settling tank. Note that it can take some time to have a pump dose change appear in the settling tank output.
Yet another aspect of this system is the concentration of chlorine to water in the feed tank. I buy 2.5 gallon chlorine and use 0.5 gallons per feed tank refill. Decreasing the amount of chlorine per feed tank fill will reduce the concentration and may be necessary (and cost effective) to reach the equilibrium you seek.
Consider to photograph or diagram your system and edit into your post, as parts of your description are somewhat ambiguous. The well pump pressure switch should have no bearing on the chlorine pump. The flow switch should detect water flow, regardless of the well pump activity, which then trips the chlorine pump to perform the injection.
But wait, there's more. In my installed system, the injector is installed vertically, from above (mandatory) but chlorine from the injector reacts with iron in the water and eventually clogs the injector back-flow valve. I've been lucky that it has to be replaced "only" every six months and the result of a failed valve is low chlorine (no chlorine) injected and an objectionable hydrogen sulfide odor in the house when water is used.
The softener and salt tank are also independent of the chlorine injection system, although I do not know if the softener resin beads would be damaged by high chlorine. I suspect that they would be, suggesting that the resin beads be replaced at the same time as the carbon filter media.
Consider to perform those above steps, but also reduce the injection volume once you restart the system. You would be safer to have insufficient chlorine and gradually increase it than to have excessive chlorine, quickly damaging the filter media and resin tank. As you get a more stable system, increase the chlorine concentration a bit at a time, checking the output of the filter tank about a week after each change.
Make notes for each change, for example, "increased injector pump value to 20 from 10" followed by "no chlorine indication on test strip." A similar note would be "decreased raw chlorine volume to 0.5 gallons" followed by "first indicator shows color." A less ideal note might be "chlorine pump stuck in on position for unknown period of time" (it happens!) followed by "test strip maxed out!"
I had to periodically disassemble the flow control valve and wipe the "slime" from the parts in order to prevent it from sticking in the on position. When I re-installed the entire system, I placed it "deeper" in the flow diagram and haven't had any sticking since that time.
